# (Just need to know that a numpy universal function can be applied to a dataframe of object dtype or not .Need to check the way i have used it

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
    X1      X2
b   AAAA    DDFD
a   BBDC    EEGH
c   CCXY    GGIM
```

Here X1 and X2 are column names of pandas dataframe & b,a,c are index. I made a Universal function and got the required result(My purpose was to remove last 2 characters of each cell of pandas dataframe). Just need to know if there is any other better way to do it.

```
sl = np.frompyfunc(lambda x : x[:-2], 1, 1)
sl(df)
```

I got the result

```
    X1  X2
b   AA  DD
a   BB  EE
c   CC  GG
```

Comment: is this what u r after ? :  df.apply(lambda x: x.str[:-2])

Comment: I don't prefer using apply or applymap , my first preference is to find a way to solve such kind of problem without using apply or applymap in such simple situations.

Comment: Also apply takes approx 2ms, but my solution takes 402 microseconds

Comment: So the way i am using this universal function is right ? Just need to know u agree or disagree

Comment: oh i think u r fine. especially with the speed gain

Comment: `df = pd.concat([df[x].str[:-2] for x in df.columns], axis=1)` is another possibility. It assumes all columns contain strings however. Works on your example df.